# Is this correct size to buffer?

Tags: c++, winapi

Is this the right size to hold a integer value on 64-bit machine plus a unicode string? or am I missing something?

```
    DWORD errorMessageID = GetLastError();
        const wchar_t msgFmt[] = L"foo baaa. Error code = %d";
        wchar_t bufferMsg[sizeof(msgFmt) +        // room for fmt message string itself
            21 +  // enough to hold numbers up to 64-bits
            sizeof(wchar_t)         // byte-terminattor
        ];
        int nBytesWritten = swprintf_s(bufferMsg,
            msgFmt,
            sizeof(msgFmt),
            errorMessageID);

        MessageBox(NULL, 
                    bufferMsg,
                    TEXT("Copy to clipboard failed"), 
                    MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
```

Comment: Why all the trouble? `auto bufferMsg = L"foo baaa. Error code = %d"s + std::to_wstring(errorMessageID);` Of course you can take care of any new features you can't use, but same idea.

Comment: Seriously consider reading about [`FormatMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @chris: The trouble is I'm still thinking like a C programmer...

Comment: @WhozCraig: In this specific case I really need to print the error code plus an message instead of the windows' system one.

Comment: @chris: How can I pass `bufferMsg` into `MessageBox()` now?

Comment: @Jack COnsider using CString class.... You can easily format string using this class ...

Comment: @Jack Use `bufferMsg.c_str()`. Your original code looks right too (assuming the 21 is correct). You actually have room for 1 more character than you need because `sizeof(msgFmt)` returns length of string literal including the terminating null character.

Comment: `FormatMessage()` solves some problems, but what a mess of an interface that function has.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Maybe in this context. To my real code it does make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not correct. The right code should look like:

```
const wchar_t msgFmt[] = L"foo baaa. Error code = %d";
wchar_t bufferMsg[sizeof(msgFmt)/sizeof(wchar_t) + // room for fmt message string itself
    21 +      // enough to hold numbers up to 64-bits
    1         // symbol-terminator
];
int nBytesWritten = swprintf_s(bufferMsg,
    sizeof(bufferMsg)/sizeof(wchar_t),
    msgFmt,
    errorMessageID);
```

In both cases you used the byte-size instead of the number of elements plus the order of params is wrong. You call of the `MessageBox()` function is correct.

Comment: Note that using `_countof` may be clearer than `sizeof()/sizeof()`.  Oh, and you've allocated 2 characters instead of 1 for the terminator. :-)

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't need to add a `1` for the null terminator since it's accounted for in the expression `sizeof(msgFmt)/sizeof(wchar_t)` (which includes the null terminator's storage in `msgFmt`). All-in-all, I think that this style of building up the buffer size to be exactly right is probably more error prone than just doing: `wchar_t bufferMsg[200]; // make sure this buffer is big enough`  It's too bad that MSVC's `snprintf()` family doesn't return how large the buffer should be in truncation situations; that would make correct dynamic allocation of the buffer easier.

Comment: @Michael, I am fully on your side with `[200]`. This is far more simple and what is more important **RELIABE**. Only there are a lot of paranoids, who do not like this style.

Comment: @Michael: There's [`_sc[w]printf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t32cf9tb.aspx) which is perfectly fine for dynamic buffer allocation.

Comment: @KirillKobelev: And if `msgFmt`  size is greater than `200`? and if rather than display in a `MessageBox()` I want to write it to a log file or send using a email or so? I don't think it's  "paranoids"

Comment: 200 is a reasonable length for a message. Longer messages are difficult to read while 200 is enough to make it clear of what is going on. In many cases it is needed to write message to several places. And what? No piece of code is ultimate solution.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the problems with the arguments passed to `swsprintf_s()` mentioned in [Kirill Kobelev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24216808/12711), there are at least a few more things that aren't quite right, even if not all of them would result in a defect:

- a `DWORD` in the Windows SDK is 32-bits, even when building for a 64-bit target. Reserving 21 characters for formatting it is a small bit of overkill, but not a bug. However, it's an indication of a misunderstanding that might result in other problems.
- `DWORD` is an unsigned type, so using "%d" to format it isn't quite right
- if you were going to format a 64-bit signed int, "%d" would still be the wrong format spec to use, since it indicates that the argument is a 32-bit int type. You would want to use something like "%lld" or "%I64d" to format a 64-bit int type.

Answer (score 0):

Manually calculating the required buffer size for the destination of an `sprintf` call is difficult to maintain. It is easier and safer to have the system perform the calculation for you. The CRT that ships with Visual Studio provides the [`_scprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t32cf9tb.aspx) family of functions for this.

The following code illustrates its usage. It implements a function that takes a format string and a variable number of arguments and returns a string that is the result of formatting:

```
std::wstring FormatString( const wchar_t* a_Format, ... ) {
    std::wstring text;
    va_list argList;
    va_start( argList, a_Format );
    // Calculate required buffer size
    size_t size = _vscwprintf( a_Format, argList ) + 1;
    va_end( argList );
    if ( size > 0 ) {
        // Dynamically construct buffer with the correct size
        std::vector<wchar_t> buffer( size );
        va_start( argList, a_Format );
        int count = _vsnwprintf_s( buffer.data(), size, size - 1,
                                   a_Format, argList );
        va_end( argList );
        if ( count >= 0 ) {
            // Construct return value
            text = std::wstring( buffer.data(), count + 1 );
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

This function returns a [`std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) object. Just like the [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) used in the implementation, it automatically manages memory for you, and no explicit cleanup code is required. To use it with Windows API calls that require an `LPCWSTR` argument call its [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) member.

Using this function in your original code condenses it down to the following:

```
DWORD errorMessageID = GetLastError();
MessageBoxW(NULL,
            FormatString( L"foo baaa. Error code = %u", errorMessageID ).c_str(),
            L"Copy to clipboard failed",
            MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
```